# Espressif Esp32 Wifi Driver SoftAP+Sta mode ... set config interface?

Tags: esp32

The *esp_wifi_set_config* method requires an interface parameter of type *wifi_interface_t*.
This an enum which has values [WIFI_IF_STA || WIFI_IF_AP]

I have my config merged from the two examples on the esp32 examples page with neccesary config params. But I am unsure what interface mode I am meant to pass from the above to set the config. I would expect a WIFI_IF_AP_STA or something.

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
    .ap = {
        .ssid = ESP_AP_WIFI_SSID,
        .ssid_len = strlen(ESP_AP_WIFI_SSID),
        .channel = ESP_AP_WIFI_CHANNEL,
        .password = ESP_AP_WIFI_PASS,
        .max_connection = AP_MAX_STA_CONN,
        .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK
    },
    .sta = {
        .ssid = ESP_STA_WIFI_SSID,
        .password = ESP_STA_WIFI_PASS,
     .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK,

        .pmf_cfg = {
            .capable = true,
            .required = false
        },
    },
};
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(
    **WHAT DO I PUT HERE? [WIFI_IF_STA : WIFI_IF_AP]
    , &wifi_config));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());
```

Comment: not the line where there's my confusion ... ```ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that `wifi_config_t` is not a struct with two members. It's a union, meaning you can store either the AP or the STA configuration but not both. So you need to create two different configuration structures, one for each mode.

As for your confusion, according to the sample [here](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=10619#p45808) you call `esp_wifi_set_config()` twice - once for the AP and once for the STA.

```
wifi_config_t ap_config = {
    .ap = {
        .ssid = ESP_AP_WIFI_SSID,
        .ssid_len = strlen(ESP_AP_WIFI_SSID),
        .channel = ESP_AP_WIFI_CHANNEL,
        .password = ESP_AP_WIFI_PASS,
        .max_connection = AP_MAX_STA_CONN,
        .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK
    }
};
wifi_config_t sta_config = {
    .sta = {
        .ssid = ESP_STA_WIFI_SSID,
        .password = ESP_STA_WIFI_PASS,
        .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK,
        .pmf_cfg = {
            .capable = true,
            .required = false
        }
    }
};

...
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_AP, &ap_config));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &sta_config));
```

Comment: reply, yeah great I didn't get back to answering this myself but I found out that I needed to set the config for each mode. Yeah probably would help I knew the nature of the union type def.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bunch of gocha-s in Espressif documentation where you have a union and they don't tell you that :)